# Git alias para o nome do branch anterior

Tags: git, alias

Onde trabalho é bem rotineiro ficar alterando entre a branch release e features branches várias vezes durante o dia. Com isso, muitas vezes tenho que escrever linhas longas, usar o tab ou alguma outra solução. Eu queria algo que tivesse como comportamento semelhante a uma variável onde guardasse o a referência anterio do branch em que estava, para assim, então, construir um alias de alteração de branch

**problema:**

```
// suponhamos que main é minha branch principal e feature-1, a secundária
$ git branch 
   * main
   * feature-1

// troca para fazer algo na branch feature-1 e depois volta par a main
$ git checkout feature-1
$ git checkout main

// troca para fazer algo na branch feature-1 e depois volta par a main
$ git checkout feature-1
$ git checkout main

etc
```

Comment: `git checkout -` (repare no hífen no final) volta para o branch que estava antes, assim vc consegue alternar entre eles (assumindo que são apenas dois branches)

Comment: Voce pode criar alias no arquivo do `.gitconfig` e criá-los para os comandos `checkout` ou `switch` para alternar entre branchs.

Comment: Ou se voce usa o VSCode como editor, pode alterar entre branchs com apenas 2 cliques....

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Funcionou perfeitamente. Com isso começo a automatizar algumas linhas de código.